# dataframe to list of list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe(df) like

```
col1, col2
a,1
b,2
```

I want to make it to a list of list like:

```
[
    [a, 1],
    [b, 2]
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: There must be a dupe of this, but basically you can just do `df.values.tolist()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
>>> df.values.tolist()
```

Comment: This works, also df.as_matrix() works but accepting this answer as it came first.

Comment: Thanks !!! happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Simply, use `as_matrix`:

```
df.as_matrix()
```

Comment: This works, thank you!